# Difference between PATH and COMPILER_PATH

Tags: linux, gcc, environment-variables

What is the difference between these environment variables in terms of gcc. When is setting a path in COMPILER_PATH preferred over PATH ?

Comment: The first google hit is http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html, could you explain what you didn't understand there? It would also be interesting to know what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

From its [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html), `COMPILER_PATH` could be used to help the compiler find the internal programs (like `cc1`, `cc1plus`, `lto1`, `collect2`, `as`, `ld`) needed to compile.

You generally don't need to worry about that (I never had myself to set `COMPILER_PATH` even when working inside GCC!). The `gcc` (or `gcc-4.7`) command is finding these internal programs quite well. Pass it the `-v` flag to understand what programs it is running. Try for example `gcc -Wall -v hello.c -o helloworld`; remember that `gcc` is just a driving program; the real work of the compiler is done by `cc1` and other internal programs (but you'll never want to run `cc1` directly).

A good reading is the [environ(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/environ.7.html) man page. It explains the (important) role of the `PATH` variable, used to find programs. See also the [execvp(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/execvp.3.html) man page.

I also suggest to read a good book, like e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

You could also read [Wikipedia's page on GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection).

In practice, don't bother about `COMPILER_PATH` but be sure that your `PATH` contains the directory containing your `gcc` (usually `gcc` is `/usr/bin/gcc` so you need `/usr/bin` early in your `PATH`). You might also have `gcc` be a symlink to [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/).

Comment: Thanks. This is problem I'm facing. "which gcc" points to /usr/bin and "which ld" points to some other directory which has a incompatible version. I way to solve this problem is setting COMPILER_PATH to /usr/bin and the other way is to prepend the path containing the compatible ld to $PATH. Which is the standard way ?